# Reference to the Inverse Mapping Theorem involving Banach spaces

Tags: analysis, reference-request, inverse-function-theorem

I would like a reference that has the proof of the following theorem:

**Inverse Mapping Theorem:** Let $X,Y$ be two Banach spaces, $\Omega \subseteq X$ an open subset and $a\in \Omega$. Suppose that $f:\Omega \to Y$ is a map of class $C^k$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}^\times \cup\{\infty\}$. If the differential $(df)_a\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is invertible, then there's a open neighborhood $U\subseteq \Omega $ of $a$ such that $f[U]\subseteq Y$ is open and $U\to f[U], x\mapsto f(x)$ is a $C^k$-diffeomorphism.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: google is your friend, by example see [here](https://math.mit.edu/~eyjaffe/Short%20Notes/Miscellaneous/Inverse%20Function%20Theorem.pdf) (this is the first result that appear with the search string "proof inverse function theorem infinite dimensional")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jean Dieudonne, *Treatise On Analysis Volume I*, page 273.